# Confusion With Etherscans representation of an Address

Tags: web3js, etherscan

I'm trying to get a list of unique addresses that have interacted with a contract. As well as some data included in the events of each transaction. In order to do this, I use the action=getLogs query when using the etherscan API. Everything is returned in hex value it seems, and while I can decode one portion of the data I need, the address will not cooperate.

What it is returning is 0x[0(x24)]address.

My questions:

What is the purpose of adding in the 24 0's?

Do I use regex to strip the 0's, or is there a more consistent approach, perphaps using web3?

I've attemped using web3.eth.abi.decodeLog, but no matter how many times I adjust, it results in "property not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a right-padded 32-byte word.

- 20 bytes for the address (0x[hex(x40)])
- 12 bytes padding (0x[0(x24)])
- Altogether, a 32-byte word

You get 40 chars representing 20 bytes in hex format, and 24 chars representing 12 zero bytes in hex format.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It definitely spells it out a little clearer. Thanks. Do you know the purpose for doing it this way?

Comment: 32-byte words are the native chunk size. Can never be too sure about motivation. I guess they opted to send the raw bytes instead of an interpretation. Thanks for accepting my answer.